# What kind of oak-like tree is this in New York?

Tags: identification, trees, oak

There's only one tree of this kind around, and it's growing in a marshy field area. Does anybody know what it is? It looks oak-like but the leaves don't match up exactly with any oak variety I know of.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a burr oak - the "corky" bark is a marker for that species. The leaves, however, look a bit "looser" than burr oak, but that could be a local variation.

Comment: Thanks, Jurp! After looking up burr oak it seems like a close enough match for me.